# Does the 100 message limit applies to one device or to every device of GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server) page, under Non-collapsible messages, it is said that after 100 messages are stored, they will be discarded by GCM. What I want to know is if these 100 messages apply to a single device or to every device.

For example, if 100 devices have my app, and those 100 devices are offline, if I send 2 messages to each device, will I lose one hundred of these messages?

Or does it means that every device can have up to 100 messages stored at GCM?

Thanks.

Comment: Im pretty sure that this limitation is per device. It wouldn't make any sense otherwise. After the limit is mentioned in the article, it speaks from "the device".

Comment: @viertausend I thought so too... I just want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Well right after the sentence you quoted it says "When the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached." "the device" implies it's for a single device, and it'd be very silly of them to mention instant messaging as an use case if the limit is global. Further evidence is that many (all?) their other services like Google maps have per-device usage limit and rarely global limit.

Comment: @Kai I know it sounds (and probably is) like a dumb question, just wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is per device.

~~~~~

Comment: upon reaching the limit, new messages will be lost or old messages?